# Nested Transactions theoretically available, but not used

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to prevent multiple object creation in an import service which runs on several server nodes in several threads. My only chance to do so seems to be using a unique constraint on the database, which is the only single point, where everything comes together again.

My services now try the creation of the object, and receive the DataIntegrityViolationException. After that the object already created by another process shall be queried and used. So far, so good.

But the query for this object is rejected by Postgres with the error message `SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]` meaning that the current transaction is broken off.

In short my code looks like this:

```
@Transactional
public void connectToCollections(Product product) {
    for (Collection coll : product.getCollections()) {
        Set<CollectionMaster> collCandidates = new HashSet<CollectionMaster>();
        CollectionMaster oldMaster = coll.getMaster();

        newMaster = collectionMasterRepository.findByTitleAndSubtitle(product, coll);

        if (newMaster == null) {
            newMaster = createNewMaster(product,coll);
            if(newMaster == null) {
                // Maybe already created by another process; search again!
                newMaster = collectionMasterRepository.findByTitleAndSubtitle(product, coll);
            }
        }

        // Do something with newMaster
    }
}

private CollectionMaster createNewMaster(Product product, Collection coll) {
    CollectionMaster oldMaster = coll.getMaster();
    CollectionMaster newMaster = null;

    oldMaster.setCreatedBy(product.getCreatedBy());
    oldMaster.setLastModifiedBy(product.getCreatedBy());

    try {
        newMaster = create(oldMaster);
    }
    catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        return null;
    }
    coll.setMaster(newMaster);

    return newMaster;
}


@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NESTED)
public CollectionMaster create(CollectionMaster collMaster) {
    CollectionMaster result = null;
    result = collectionMasterRepository.saveAndFlush(collMaster);
    return result;
}
```

The entry point is connectToCollections. A CollectionMaster is queried, then if not found, tried to create, and if unsuccessful, queried again.
It seems that the @Transactional attribute for propagation as NESTED (or REQUIRES_NEW) are ignored, and no savepoints on the database are set or used, where normally the used technology stack should be able to do so. What am I missing?

The relevant part of the pom.xml looks like this:

```
<hibernate.version>4.1.7.Final</hibernate.version>
<postgresql.version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
<commons-dbcp2.version>2.0.1</commons-dbcp2.version>
<spring.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring-data-jpa.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
<aspectj.version>1.8.0</aspectj.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-dbcp2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And finally the relevant part of the Spring application context:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="${database.dialect}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="javax.persistence.validation.factory" value-ref="validator" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl}"/>
            <entry key="org.hibernate.envers.track_entities_changed_in_revision" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mvb.vlx.model" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj" />
```

Java version is jdk1.7.0_40

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've never used Postgres. Nested transaction support can vary a lot between DB vendors and drivers.

However, I think the problem might be this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    return null;
}
```

At the point when the create fails, the transaction is marked as failed by the database, but you're ignoring this in Java. So then I suspect it would fail later when you try to commit it.

I think your options are to either fail and retry the whole block (connectToCollections()), or do createNewMaster() in a new/nested transaction.

If you go with the latter, remember that @Transactional does NOT work on private methods because of the way how the proxy gets created. You can still do it programmatically, Spring's TransactionTemplate and RetryTemplate are excellent tools for this.

Also I'm not sure I understood correctly, but if you meant putting 'NESTED' on connectToCollections(), well, that won't make a difference of course (you'd want to nest createNewMaster()).

Comment: @Transactional on private methods works with aspectj, which we use. When I explicitly autowire the transaction manager and start the transaction manually, I get the exception "JPA dialect does not support nested transactions", even if I configure HibernateDialect. It remains a strange phenomenon...

Comment: Till the end I was not able to create nested or "really" new transactions. But the RetryTemplate did the trick! Thanks.